# Cannot construct DbContext without using OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I am developing a .NET CORE MVC 2.1 Web Application with a DbContext declared in a DLL (EF Core 2.1).

I would like to configure the context using `IServiceCollection.AddContext<GladContext`> but if I do not *ALSO* configures it `DbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` I am told that *No database provider has been configured for this DbContext* despite having a constructor taking a `DbContextOptions<GladContext>`

```
    public GladContext(DbContextOptions<GladContext> options, IGladConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider) : base(options)
    {
        _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        GladOptionsBuilderHelper.ConfigureDefaultOptionsBuilder(optionsBuilder, _connectionStringProvider.ConnectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

The `IGladConnectionStringProvider` is my current workaround and that is acceptable if it wasn't because I now need to configure both `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and `DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>`

```
public static class GladOptionsBuilderHelper
{

    public const string GladMigrationsHistory = "__GladMigrationsHistory";
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext> CreateDefaultTypedOptionsBuilder(string connectionString) 
    {

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>();

        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
            {
                options.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                options.MigrationsHistoryTable(GladMigrationsHistory, EntityBase.SchemaName);
            })
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));

        return optionsBuilder;
    }


    public static void ConfigureDefaultOptionsBuilder(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
            {
                options.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                options.MigrationsHistoryTable(GladMigrationsHistory, EntityBase.SchemaName);
            })
            .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));

    }
}
```

The `DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>` is used in `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<GladContext>`

Can you can tell me how to use `AddContext` to configure `GladContext` or how to construct a `DbContextOptionsBuilder` from a `DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>` or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration part of it is an override of the IServiceCollection.AddDbContext().

So, when you call AddDbContext, just add your options into the parentheses like so:

```
var connectionString = "CONNECTION-STRING-HERE";

services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(true)
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true));



public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have confused my self at one point :). I am still stuck with the DbContextOptionsBuilder and the DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>. Any hints on how to eliminate one of them?

Comment: I've updated my answer - That there is literally all the config/setup you need to get the DbContext registered. The constructor passing the options to the : base() is needed as a minimum to ensure that the configuration gets setup properly. 

All of the code in your static class example can go.. And just replace it with the services.AddDbContext example code i have provided

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the update. According to my understanding AddDbContext requires a DbContextOptionsBuilder and the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<GladContext> (needed for the migration tool) requires a DbContextOptionsBuilder<GladContext>. Thus I now have duplicate code for configuration. Its only a few lines but it is not DRY :)